# Handling multiple TCP connections with Akka Actors

Tags: scala, tcp, akka, actor

I'm trying to set up a simple TCP server using [akka](http://akka.io/) actors that should allow multiple clients to be connected simultaneously. I reduced my problem to the following simple program:

```
package actorfail
import akka.actor._, akka.io._, akka.util._
import scala.collection.mutable._
import java.net._

case class Foo()

class ConnHandler(conn: ActorRef) extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case Foo() => conn ! Tcp.Write(ByteString("foo\n"))
  }
}

class Server(conns: ArrayBuffer[ActorRef]) extends Actor {
  import context.system
  println("Listing on 127.0.0.1:9191")
  IO(Tcp) ! Tcp.Bind(self, new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 9191))
  def receive = {
    case Tcp.Connected(remote, local) =>
      val handler = context.actorOf(Props(new ConnHandler(sender)))
      sender ! Tcp.Register(handler)
      conns.append(handler)
  }
}

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    implicit val system = ActorSystem("Test")
    val conns = new ArrayBuffer[ActorRef]()
    val server = system.actorOf(Props(new Server(conns)))
    while (true)  {
      println(s"Sending some foos")
      for (c <- conns) c ! Foo()
      Thread.sleep(1000)
    }
  }
}
```

It binds to localhost:9191 and accepts multiple connections, adding the connection handlers to a global array and periodically sending the string `"foo"` to each connection. Now when I try to connect with more than one client simultaneously, only the first one gets the "foo"s. When I open a second connection, it doesn't get sent any foo's, rather I get the following type of log message:

```
Sending some foos
[INFO] [03/27/2015 21:24:07.331] [Test-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6] [akka://Test/deadLetters] Message [akka.io.Tcp$Write] from Actor[akka://Test/user/$a/$b#-308726290] to Actor[akka://Test/deadLetters] was not delivered. [7] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
```

I understand that this would mean that the target actor to which we try to send the `Tcp.Write` command is no longer accepting messages. But why is that? Can you help me understand the underlying issue? How can I make this work?

Comment: Mutable state within an actor is fine, but it looks like you are trying to access the Server actor's connections from outside the actor.  This isn't very Akka-y.  Why not have the Server manage the pool of connections AND sending messages on those connections?

Comment: @Gangstead I just tested using an actor to send the Foos and that seems to work, can you elaborate on the technical aspects of this or where this is documented? I was hoping there is actually a way to mix actors with other concurrency models. In reality the code accessing the actor from the outside is a loop reading lines from a `Source` in a blocking manner. Of course I could transform that into an actor, but it would be a bit bulky to formulate as a state machine. I would prefer having a way of dispatching a message from the outside, given only the ActorRef.

Comment: You got an answer from the head of the Akka project.  He provided some documentation links.  I don't think you can mix up concurrency models as you are hoping.

Comment: @Gangstead Well according to his answer I can :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two issues with the code presented above:

- sending mutable state in actor messages and mutating it in a non-threadsafe fashion
- including unstable references in Props

Before I elaborate, please consider reading the docs, [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.9/general/jmm.html) and [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.9/scala/actors.html#Dangerous_Variants), this is all covered there.

## Mutable Messages

ArrayBuffer is not thread-safe, but you pass it from the main routine to different actors who then independently (concurrently) modify it. This will lead to the loss of updates or to the corruption of the data structure itself. On the other hand, without proper synchronization it is not guaranteed that the main thread will ever see the modifications, since the compiler could in principle determine that the buffer does not change within the `while` loop and optimize the code accordingly.

Instead of relying upon shared mutable state, actors only send messages. In this case the solution is to lift the `while` loop into an actor (but scheduling a message to `self` after a second instead of the blocking `Thread.sleep(1000)` call). The connection handlers then only need to be passed the `ActorRef` for this `foo` sender actor, they’ll send it a message to register themselves and then that actor keeps the list of active connections inside it encapsulated scope. This has the benefit that you can use DeathWatch to also remove the connections when they terminate.

## Unstable References in Props

The problematic code: `Props(new ConnHandler(sender))`

Props are constructed from an actor factory, which is taken as a by-name argument in this case; the whole `new` expression is evaluated at a later time, whenever such an actor is being initialized—possibly on a different thread. This means that `sender` is also evaluated later, from that context of execution, and therefore it will likely be `deadLetters` (if the parent actor is not currently running—and if it is, `sender` will likely point to the wrong actor altogether).

The solution here is documented [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.9/scala/actors.html#Recommended_Practices).

Comment: I only modify the ArrayBuffer in one single location, I was under the impression that an actor can only process one message at a time? of course it's still broken, since there is another actor that reads the array, but that's merely for demonstration purposes, it's not like that in the real program. You are spot on on the more interesting problem though, I will try out the solution later :)

Comment: Even if you modify the Array only in one location (which you are right is actually safe in this particular, narrow case), external observers may see the buffer in inconsistent states or possibly even taking steps “backwards” as actors bounce around threads and CPU cores. Shared mutable state has more than just the obvious class of problems ;-)

Comment: It's just a simple example, I don't do any such thing in the real program. Closing the props over the constructor arguments worked, thanks!